# How To Make WCF routing service log message to SQL server

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to use Routing Service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517422.aspx) to route the data from clients to other end points. I have multiple clients and the end point which is called from routing service is located at a third party.

I also need to Log every transaction passed through routing service into SQL Database.

The problem is I can't write custom code in routing service as it's working from configuration files.  Given that I can't write custom code in these classes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create a class library and sign it with strong key.

2)create RoutingServiceBehavior class this class will implement IServiceBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector interfaces, the code for message interception will be in this class:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace Services.RoutingServiceBehavior
{
    public class RoutingServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            // This is your envelop
            string s = request.ToString();
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {

        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {
            foreach (ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
                {
                    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
                }
            }  

        }

        public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

3) Create RoutingServiceBehaviorElement class, this class will implement BehaviorExtensionElement interface:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;

namespace Services.RoutingServiceBehavior
{
    public class RoutingServiceBehaviorElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(RoutingServiceBehavior); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new RoutingServiceBehavior();
        }
    }
}
```

4)Build your project.
5)Add your assembly to GAC.
6)Open machine.config and add the name of your assembly under `<behaviorExtensions>` it shall look like that:

```
<add name="RoutingServiceBehavior" type="Services.RoutingServiceBehavior.RoutingServiceBehaviorElement, Services.RoutingServiceBehavior, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
```

7) add the name of your service behavior in your wcf service under  `<serviceDebug>`

```
<RoutingServiceBehavior/>
```

8)Make sure that the assembly dlls are included in your WCF service.

Comment: Cheers matey, that was driving me nuts!